# Transaction id is invalid 10609

Tags: php, paypal, nvp

I'm very new to paypal api, I've followed [this](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/05/getting-started-with-the-paypal-api/) tutorial and adapted the code to my needs.

I'd like to make a basic Authorization & Capture in 3 steps but I always fail in capturing

1. Customer land to paypal_pay_redirect.php for login into paypal and make a paymet
2. The payment is fine and we land to paypal_success.php, here I request the Authorization and keep the TRANSACTIONID for the next step
3. paypal_capture.php I use the transactionid for capture the payment but I always get "10609: Transaction id is invalid"

here the code, where is the mistake?

thanks

paypal_lib.php

```php
<?php
  // code from http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/05/getting-started-with-the-paypal-api/
class Paypal {
  /**
   * Last error message(s)
   * @var array
   */
  protected $_errors = array();

  /**
   * API Credentials
   * Use the correct credentials for the environment in use (Live / Sandbox)
   * @var array
   */
  protected $_credentials = array(
                  'USER' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                  'PWD' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                  'SIGNATURE' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
                  );
  /**
   * API endpoint
   * Live - https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp
   * Sandbox - https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
   * @var string
   */
  protected $_endPoint = 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp';

  /**
   * API Version
   * @var string
   */
  protected $_version = '74.0';

  /**
   * Make API request
   *
   * @param string $method string API method to request
   * @param array $params Additional request parameters
   * @return array / boolean Response array / boolean false on failure
   */
  public function request($method,$params = array()) {
    $this -> _errors = array();
    if( empty($method) ) { //Check if API method is not empty
      $this -> _errors = array('API method is missing');
      return false;
    }

    //Our request parameters
    $requestParams = array_merge(
                 array(
                       'METHOD' => $method,
                       'VERSION' => $this -> _version
                       ),
                 $this -> _credentials
                 );

    //Building our NVP string
    $request = http_build_query(array_merge($requestParams, $params));

    //cURL settings
    $curlOptions = array (
              CURLOPT_URL => $this -> _endPoint,
              CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,
              CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
              CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
              CURLOPT_POST => 1,
              CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $request
              );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch,$curlOptions);

    //Sending our request - $response will hold the API response
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    //Checking for cURL errors
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
      $this -> _errors = curl_error($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return false;
      //Handle errors
    } else {
      curl_close($ch);
      $responseArray = array();
      parse_str($response,$responseArray); // Break the NVP string to an array
      return $responseArray;
    }
  }
}

?>
```

paypal_pay_redirect.php

```php
<?php
require("paypal_lib.php");

//Our request parameters
$requestParams = array(
               'RETURNURL' => 'https://www.domain.com/paypal_success.php',
               'CANCELURL' => 'https://www.domain.com/paypal_fail.php'
               );

$orderParams = array(
             'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => "57.00",
             'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT' => '0',
             'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => 'EUR',
   'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT' => "57.00"
             );

$item = array(
          'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
          'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
          'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0' => "57.00",
   'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0' => '1'
          );

$paypal = new Paypal();
$response = $paypal -> request('SetExpressCheckout',$requestParams + $orderParams + $item);
if(is_array($response) && $response['ACK'] == 'Success') { //Request successful
  $token = $response['TOKEN'];
  header( 'Location: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=' . urlencode($token) );
 }


?>
```

paypal_success.php

```php
<?php
require("paypal_lib.php");

if( isset($_GET['token']) && !empty($_GET['token']) ) { // Token parameter exists
  // Get checkout details, including buyer information.
  // We can save it for future reference or cross-check with the data we have
  $paypal = new Paypal();
  $checkoutDetails = $paypal -> request('GetExpressCheckoutDetails', array('TOKEN' => $_GET['token']));

  // Complete the checkout transaction
  $requestParams = array(
             'TOKEN' => $_GET['token'],
             'PAYMENTACTION' => 'Authorization',
             'PAYERID' => $_GET['PayerID'],
             'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => '57', // Same amount as in the original request
             'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => 'EUR' // Same currency as the original request
             );

  $response = $paypal -> request('DoExpressCheckoutPayment',$requestParams);
  if( is_array($response) && $response['ACK'] == 'Success') { // Payment successful
    // We'll fetch the transaction ID for internal bookkeeping
    $transactionId = $response['PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID'];
    echo "OK id: ".$transactionId;
    var_dump($response);
  }

 var_dump($checkoutDetails);

 }
?>
```

paypal_capture.php

```php
<?php
require("paypal_lib.php");

$paypal = new Paypal();

// Complete the checkout transaction
$requestParams = array(
               'AMT' => '57.00',
               'AUTHORIZATIONID' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', //what I get in paypal_success.php
               'CURRENCYCODE' => 'EUR',
               'COMPLETETYPE' => 'Complete', // Same amount as in the original request
               );

$response = $paypal -> request('DoCapture',$requestParams);

var_dump($response);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

First, in paypal_pay_redirect.php, add `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION => 'Authorization'` to `$orderParams`.

Second, in paypal_success.php, change `PAYMENTACTION` TO `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION`.

Here's why:

In your SetExpressCheckout call, if you don't set `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION`, PayPal assumes that it will be `Sale`.  And if this is set to `Sale` in your SetExpressCheckout call, then PayPal will only allow you to set it to `Sale` on your DoExpressCheckoutPayment call.

Additionally, in your DoExpressCheckoutPayment call, you're mixing new and old-style variable names.  (Some variables, such as `PAYMENTACTION`, were renamed when PayPal introduced parallel payments for Express Checkout.  `PAYMENTACTION` is the old style; `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION` is the new style.)  When you mix old-style and new-style names like this, PayPal recognizes variables using one style, and ignores the other.  In your case, `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT` and `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE` are being recognized, but `PAYMENTACTION` is being ignored.

The combination of these two factors means that your transaction is most likely being run as a Sale transaction, not an Authorization.  Since you can't capture against a Sale transaction (since it's technically already captured), PayPal responds by saying that the transaction ID is invalid.